# selecting specific cards in with a double nested sql query sybase

Tags: sql, group-by, nested, sybase

```
SELECT card_num, 
       COUNT(merchant_code) 
from e_transaction 
where trans_date between '20161017 00:00' and '20161017 23:59' 
and channelid='02' 
and trans_code='P' 
and card_num in (select card_num, 
                        sum(trans_amount) 
                 from e_transaction 
                 where trans_date between '20161017 00:00' and '20161017 23:59' 
                 and channelid='02' 
                 and trans_code='T' 
                 and card_num not in (select card_num 
                                      from e_transaction 
                                      where trans_date between '20160724 00:00' and '20161016 23:59') 
                 group by card_num 
                 having sum(trans_amount) > 100000) 
group by card_num 
having count (merchant_code) > 1
```

I keep getting a syntax error for this query but can't seem to find where the error is. I am trying to spool multiple card_num with same merchant_code for today with trans_amount greater than 100000 and not found between 20160724 and yesterday

error messages

> [Incorrect syntax near ','] [Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'group']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After properly formatting the query it is easy to see the problem. In your first nested select you wrote:

```
and card_num in (select card_num, 
                        sum(trans_amount) 
                 from e_transaction 
                 ...)
```

The `in` is expecting a single column but your nested select is giving two. All you need to do is remove the `sum(trans_amount)` from the nested select as follows:

```
and card_num in (select card_num
                 from e_transaction 
                 ...)
```

Comment: Thank you Gilad. It runs fine now

Comment: @brucewayne - Great, glad to hear